# Fill an array with random values

Tags: assembly, parameter-passing, masm, irvine32

I'm in an assembly language class and we are doing an exercise where we need to pass parameters on the stack in order to generate *n* random numbers in a specific range.

The problems that I'm having:
1. My random numbers are not in the range that I am specifying.
2. When I return this array and attempt to sort it and display it again, the array is populated with different values.

I'm thinking these problems are somehow related to the way I'm passing my parameters.

```
TITLE Program 4         (Project04.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
intro_1 BYTE    "Composite Numbers          Programmed by ",0
prompt_1 BYTE   "This program generates random numbers in the range [100 .. 999],",0
prompt_2 BYTE   "displays the original list, sorts the list, and calculates the ",0
prompt_3 BYTE   "median value. Finally, it displays the list sorted in descending order.",0
prompt_4 BYTE   "How many numbers should be generated? [10 .. 200]: ",0
space3  BYTE    "   ",0
errorMessage BYTE   "Invalid input ",0
userNum DWORD   ?
min     =   10
max     =   200
lo      =   100
hi      =   999
array   DWORD   max DUP(?)

.code
main PROC
call    Introduction
push    OFFSET userNum
call    getData
;call   Randomize
push OFFSET array
push userNum
call fillArray1
push OFFSET array
push userNum
call displayList
call crlf
call crlf
push OFFSET array
push userNum
call sortList
push OFFSET array
push userNum 
call displayList
exit
main ENDP


    Introduction PROC
        mov edx, OFFSET intro_1
        call    WriteString
        call    crlf
        mov edx, OFFSET prompt_1
        call    WriteString
        call    crlf
        mov edx, OFFSET prompt_2
        call    WriteString
        call    crlf
        mov edx, OFFSET prompt_3
        call    WriteString
        call    crlf    
        call    crlf
        ret
    Introduction ENDP

;Get Data

    getData PROC

    getUserData:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        mov edx, OFFSET prompt_4
        call    WriteString
        call    ReadInt
        mov     userNum, eax
        ;call   crlf

    ;validate
        cmp eax, max
        ja  error1
        cmp eax, min
        jb  error1
        pop ebp
        ret
        error1:
            mov edx, OFFSET errorMessage
            call    WriteString
            call    crlf
            jmp getUserData

    getData ENDP

;Fill array

    fillArray1 PROC
        fillArray:
            push    ebp
            mov ebp,esp
            pushad          ; save registers
            mov esi,[ebp+12]    ; offset of array
            mov ecx,[ebp+8] ; array size
            cmp ecx,0       ; ECX == 0?
            je  L2          ; yes: skip over loop
            mov edx, hi 
            sub edx, lo

        L1:
            mov eax, edx
            call    RandomRange ; from the link library
            add eax, lo
            mov [esi], eax
            add esi, 4
            loop    L1

        L2: 
            popad           ; restore registers
            pop ebp
            ret 8           ; clean up the stack

    fillArray1 ENDP

;Sort List

    sortList PROC
        push    ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        mov ecx, [ebp + 8]
        dec ecx         ; decrement count by 1

        L1:
            push ecx            ; save outer loop count
            mov esi, [ebp + 12]     ; point to first value

        L2: 
            mov eax,[esi]       ; get array value
            cmp [esi+4],eax ; compare a pair of values
            jge L3          ; if [esi] <= [edi], don't exch
            xchg eax,[esi+4]    ; exchange the pair
            mov [esi],eax

        L3: 
            add esi,4       ; move both pointers forward
            loop L2     ; inner loop

            pop ecx     ; retrieve outer loop count
            loop L1     ; else repeat outer loop

        L4 :
            pop ebp
            ret 8  
    sortList ENDP

;Display Median

    displayMedian PROC
    displayMedian ENDP
```

I think my return value may be off in my fillArray procedure?

The displayList procedure:

```
;Display list

    displayList PROC
        push    ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        mov ecx, [ebp + 8]
        jecxz   farewell
        mov esi, [ebp + 12]         ;set counter for the linebreak

    Print:
        mov eax, [ebx]
        call WriteDec
        dec esi
        jnz Spaces

    linebreak:
        call crlf
        mov esi, 10
        jmp Next

    Spaces:
        cmp esi, 0          ;if there has been ten elements, go to next line
        je  linebreak
        mov edx, OFFSET space3
        call WriteString

    Next:
        add ebx, 4
        loop Print


    pop ebp
    ret 8

    displayList ENDP
```

The getData procedure that accepts a reference param:

```
;Get Data

    getData PROC
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        pushad
        mov esi, [ebp + 8] ;move the address of the userNum

    getUserData:
        mov edx, OFFSET prompt_4
        call    WriteString
        call    ReadInt
        mov     userNum, eax
        mov     esi, userNum    ;move the userNum to the address
        ;call   crlf

    ;validate
        cmp eax, max
        ja  error1
        cmp eax, min
        jb  error1
        pop ebp
        ret
        error1:
            mov edx, OFFSET errorMessage
            call    WriteString
            call    crlf
            jmp getUserData

    getData ENDP
```

When I made this change, after I enter the number of random numbers to be printed, the program crashes.

Comment: Have you tried to find the problem?  If so, what have you found?

Answer (score 0):

`fillArray` and `sortList` are working properly, I have tested them.

`getData` has a bug (big one indeed) in the `error1` path, after printing the error message you jump back to `getUserData` that again creates the stack frame.
Move this creation above the `getUserData` label, just below `getData`.

`Introduction` should work properly (not tested tough).

The `main` procedure has some issues:

```
call    Introduction            ;OK

push    OFFSET userNum
call    getData                 ;getData takes no params
                                ;Either update getData (don't forget ret 04h)
                                ;or remove the push


;call   Randomize

push OFFSET array
push userNum
call fillArray1                 ;This should work

push OFFSET array
push userNum
call displayList                ;Don't know, no code for displayList

call crlf
call crlf
push OFFSET array
push userNum
call sortList                   ;This should work

;push OFFSET array              ;<-- This is commented
push userNum 
call displayList                ;!! You are not passing the array to display
                                ;That's why you will see different values
```

It seems that you forget to update your `main` after refactoring the others functions.

---

## Follow up

The `displayList` procedure seems wrong to be because:

1. You never initialize `ebx`
2. `esi` will holds the array pointer but you seems to use it as a counter
3. `farewell` is not defined anywhere

I think this new `displayList` may work (**Please, please, please, note that I haven't even compiled it, I don't have NASM, nor planning installing it**)

```
 ;Array
 ;Number of elements
 ;Elements per line   
 displayList PROC
        push    ebp
        mov ebp, esp

        push esi
        push ecx
        push edx

        mov esi, [ebp + 16]      ;Array
        mov ecx, [ebp + 12]      ;Items in array

    PrePrint:
        mov edx, [ebp + 8]       ;Counter for linebreaks

    Print:
        jecxz End
         
        lodsd
        call WriteDec            ;Print items

        mov edx, OFFSET space3
        call WriteString         ;Print space

        dec ecx
        dec edx
        jnz Print

        call crlf
    jmp PrePrint

    End:
        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop esi
 
        pop ebp
        ret 12

    displayList ENDP
```

**Note** This new `displayList` takes **3** arguments:

```
push OFFSET array
push userNum
push 10              ;Items per line
call displayList
```

If you want to hardcode the items per line and remove the past parameters, you edit the function, remember to update the `ret 12` and the `[ebp + xx]` references!

---

In your new `getData` you forget to do a `popad` before the `pop ebp` and to replace `ret` with `ret 04h`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! According to my instructions, getData is supposed to take is supposed to take a reference parameter. I interpreted this as the OFFSET of userNum. The code I implemented is above.